# VS Code: Change color of variables?

Tags: python, variables, visual-studio-code, settings, syntax-highlighting

I use VS Code, and wanted to change the color of the variables in Python code. I read that I have to add

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#ff0000",
    }
```

to the settings.json file. I've added it to the settings.json in my open folder, and also tried to append it to the global settings.json file. But none of it worked.

Now I don't know what else to try.
Does anyone know how to do it?

EDIT:

Here is the code from the local json file:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\JannR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "activityBar.background": "#131a29",
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#A4BD00",
        "titleBar.activeForeground": "#000000",
        "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#c4d16e",
        "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#000000",
        "minimapSlider.background": "#a4bd003a",
        "minimapSlider.hoverBackground": "#a4bd004d",
        "minimapSlider.activeBackground": "#a4bd0060",
        "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#a4bd001f",
        "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#a4bd0033",
        "scrollbarSlider.background": "#a4bd000e",
        "editorGroup.border": "#A4BD00",
        "editorGroup.dropBackground": "#a4bd0060",
        "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#a4bd0060",
        "tab.activeBackground": "#a4bd002a",
        "tab.activeBorder": "#000000",
        "tab.unfocusedActiveForeground": "#5b6350",
    },
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#ff0000",
    }
}
```

And here from the global:

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "editor.cursorStyle": "block-outline",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "auto-close-tag.fullMode": true,
    "auto-close-tag.SublimeText3Mode": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\JannR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "[python]": {
    
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "python.showStartPage": false,
    "workbench.tips.enabled": false,
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\JannR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "FireFly Pro",
    "window.title": "${activeEditorShort} - ${folderName} - ${appName}",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    

        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#0000ff",
    },
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#ff0000",
    },
    "vs-color-picker.autoLaunchDelay": 10,
    "windowColors. DeleteSettingsFileUponExit": true
}
```

EDIT V2:

[Screenshot of variable description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFABZ.png)

Comment: I'm currently unable to post the content, but I added it on the very buttom, with no indentation. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Nahh, I didn't mean no indentation, but just the normal indentation from the curly brackets that include all the code.

Comment: Maybe I can edit the question in a few minutes... But which settings.json file should i send the content from? The local in the folder or the global?

Comment: But i got the exact same indentation as you have it.

Comment: If you didn't noticed (i'm not complaining), I've now edited the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could have a check like this? It works well on my computer.

[image]

[image]

Update:

You are using the theme of `FireFly Pro`. The `"variables": "#ff0000"` seems to not work, while it will work when using some other themes. This is because when you are using a different **color theme**, the variable is under a different scope.

For example:

The theme of `Dark+`(*Open the Command Palette: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes*):

[image]

The theme of `FireFly Pro`:

[image]

So if you want to modify it under `FireFly Pro` color theme, you can customize it like this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope":"source.python",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#00fff2",
              "fontStyle": "bold"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: I now did this, and at the point `foreground` isn't something listed. So theoretically I shouldn't have any extensions overwriting this. But on the top color listings there are background and foregroundcolors. I'll edit the question and add the screen shot.

Comment: @Jannis Could you disable all the extensions just leave the python extension? Remember to switch the color theme to the built-in one.

Comment: Yes, I've done that, and now the variable is red. Should i now turn them on one by one so that I see which extension did it?

Comment: I enabled them now again, and it's the `FireFly Pro` color theme. Can I somehow change the variable color of it?

Comment: @Jannis It seems can overwrite the color customization in the settings.json. Could you switch to another theme?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Should I switch forever to another theme?

Comment: @Jannis Could you have a look at the update of this answer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't seen it. But now that i tried this it works. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again, but is there then also another scope or way to set the color of modules to another then variables? I mean theoretically those also just are variables that inherit from different classes, but is it although possible?

Comment: @Jannis It's impossible in `FireFly Pro` theme.  Because it has not semantic token type. But you can get it in another theme, such as Dark+. Then you can modify it with `semanticTokenColorCustomizations`. You can refer to [this page](https://medium.com/@danromans/how-to-customize-semantic-token-colorization-with-visual-studio-code-ac3eab96141b) to know how to modify it.

Comment: @Steven-MSFT It is not impossible, just add ```"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,``` into your settings.json file, or if you are the developer of the theme (i.e. you made a fork) just add ```"semanticHighlighting": true,``` to your .json file.

Answer (score 2):

Your theme does not support the python highlighter syntaxes, to enable it you have to add the following to your settings.json (Ctrl + , to open it):

settings.json:

```json
{
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
}
```

Notice that when you open or paste code, it may take a moment to the editor to update the colors, so be patient.

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide